# Save Edited (Texture Paint) Image Sequence

Tags: python, image, texture-painting

I load an image texture (of 3 frames) as a material node.
I draw on all (3) frames in texture paint mode.

[image: save]

I want to save all modified images at once, preferably with python.
How can I save all images of the image sequence at once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just call [**`bpy.ops.image.save_sequence()`**](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.image.html?highlight=save_sequence#bpy.ops.image.save_sequence) within the *Image Editor*.

#### Override the context

If you would like to call the operator from another area, you can [override the context](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add):

**Blender 3.2+**

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

for area in context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
        with context.temp_override(area=area):
            bpy.ops.image.save_sequence()
        break
```

**Blender 2.8+**

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

for area in C.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
        override = C.copy()
        override['area'] = area
        bpy.ops.image.save_sequence(override)
        break
```

Console output:

```
Info: 3 image(s) will be saved in /tmp/
Info: Saved /tmp/untitled_0003.exr
Info: Saved /tmp/untitled_0002.exr
Info: Saved /tmp/untitled_0001.exr
```

#### Switch the area

If there is no *Image Editor* available, you can also switch the current area to the *Image Editor*, assign the sequence, call the operator and reset the area to its *old* type:

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context
img_seq = bpy.data.images['untitled_0001.exr']

# Store current area
area = C.area
old_type = area.type

# Set the area type and assign the sequence
area.type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
area.spaces.active.image = img_seq

# Call the operator and reset the area
bpy.ops.image.save_sequence()
area.type = old_type
```

Console output:

```
Info: 3 image(s) will be saved in /tmp/
Info: Saved /tmp/untitled_0003.exr
Info: Saved /tmp/untitled_0002.exr
Info: Saved /tmp/untitled_0001.exr
```

---

#### Custom operator

Operator demo based on the `operator_node.py` template that comes with Blender in order to save the image sequence of the selected *Image* node in the *Node Editor*:

```
import bpy

class NodeOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "node.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Node Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        space = context.space_data
        return space.type == 'NODE_EDITOR' and \
            context.active_node.type=='TEX_IMAGE'

    def execute(self, context):
        image_sequence = context.active_node.image
        if image_sequence.source == 'SEQUENCE':
            # Store current area
            area = context.area
            old_type = area.type
            # Set the area type and assign the sequence
            area.type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
            area.spaces.active.image = image_sequence
            # Call the operator and reset the area
            bpy.ops.image.save_sequence()
            area.type = old_type
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(NodeOperator)
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NodeOperator)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: 1. What if there is no Image Editor, just a node graph? 2. Can we call the function from the ui?

Comment: re 1: you'd have to switch the area temporarily see the link. re 2: Sure, `layout.operator("image.save_sequence")` (already part of the header menu, *Image Editor > Image > Save Sequence*) Does this answer your question(s)? @Leander

Comment: Actually quite so. It seems I just completely overlooked that operator/button. Obligatory, but futile follow up: Can we access that functionality without ops?

Comment: Not sure, need to investigate. AFAICT there is no way to access each image (buffer) individually so I don't see any potential improvements of a low-level solution. We would have to change the frame using `frame_set()` and save the result which is quite expensive and slow, I guess. The operator on the other hand just saves the image buffer already in memory: https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/editors/space_image/image_ops.c#L2201 @Leander

Comment: I had tried your suggestion, but the image buffer was not replaced after frame_set(). Your argument about performance makes a lot of sense though.